# Max number for webservice to service

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, soap

What is the maximum number that a webservice  can take and process request at the same time? Is it possible to set some limit and what might be the problem if webservice gets too many request and how to solve this problem on that situation?

Answer (score 0):

The number of the requests handled by the web service at a given time is depend on the architecture of your web server. If you want to improve the number of requests served by the server at a given time you should improve the architecture and the performance.

Please refer [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647682.aspx) for more information on webservice performance.

You can set limits by implementing a model on top of that by controlling the user requests hit the server in a given time. the most recommended model is to implement this in your middleware platform That will be a security measure too. You can get rid of security threats like Denial-of-Service attack.

In middleware solutions like WSO2 API Manager, Throttling policies have implemented as a solution for access controlling. You can check the [docuementations on Throttling Policies](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Introducing+Throttling+Use-Cases) for more information on how number of hits for a server at a given time is controlled by using middleware logic.